# javascript/jQuery code generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-generation

I'm wondering if there is a tool out there that does any javascript code generation.  I'm asking because the team I'm on are not web developers.  They are VB6 developers.

We  are looking at a AJAX, JavaScript/jQuery, JSON, webservices model and was wondering if there were any tools that would provide the basics for JavaScript templates (i.e. jQuery AJAX calls)?  Obviously a tool like this, might make the change from VB6 to JavaScript a little easier.  It also seems like Code Generation is a buzz word so I thought there might be something for JavaScript.

If not, do you think this would be a good tool to work on (for the basics, as they would have to edit and modify to fit the need of the page)?  Or do you think it is a waste of time?

Comment: just by a proper keyboard with a "generate javascript" button...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I think this is a complete waste of time. Spend a little time to teach your developers javascript or go another route. Endless time will be wasted tracking down bugs by blindly copying and pasting template data all over the place.

Comment: Thanks Keith for your answer.  It appears that many people agree with you.  I was hoping there was an opposing view as it would of made the question more complete, however, maybe there is a reason why there is no opposing view :)

Answer (score 2):

If you feel comfortable in the Java world then you can use as well. So you can code in Java and have the code be generated to Javascript etc.

From the [GWT SDK documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/de/webtoolkit/learnmore-sdk.html):

> The GWT SDK provides a core set of Java APIs and libraries that allow you to productively build user interfaces and logic for the browser client. You then compile that source code to JavaScript. All that runs in the end is plain ol' JavaScript in the browser. Oh, and you can mix in and interoperate with JavaScript in your source code as well.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a similar thought and found this https://learning.divi.space/jquery-function-generator/

It is a Jquery function generator.

Comment: This answer could be improved by editing it to document more specific details. Providing just a link with no additional context won't contribute after the link is no longer available.